# How do I make random choice when playing script on console?

Tags: javascript, random, console

So basically, my script places random bets on a website and I want it to choose it randomly EVERY bet and I wanted to make it random choice between 'red' and 'black'
so i did

```
var betColor = 'random.nextBoolean() ? red : black;';
```

But it choose the color randomly, and used it for all the bets, I want it to choose randomly every bet. Any help?

Comment: Why are you setting `betColor` to a string?

Comment: `random.nextBoolean()` is Java, not Javascript.

Comment: I can send you full code: http://pastebin.com/fh6bDgpf

Answer (score 0):

You are currently setting the `betColor` to a String. You should use something like this

```
var betColor = (Math.random() < 0.5) ? 'red' : 'black'
```

Comment: In that case I don't know what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: It basically makes a lot of bets, and I want it that BEFORE every bet would do Math.random() < 0.5) thingy or choose random between 'red' and 'black'

Comment: Can't you then just call `betColor = (Math.random() < 0.5) ? 'red' : 'black'` before every bet?

Answer (score 0):

```
var randomColor = function() {
    var colors = ['red', 'black'];
    var color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
    return color;
};
```

Every time you call the function it will return another random choice.